# Weird binary comparison of 64 bit signed integers

Tags: c++, logic, c++14

I am having an issue where it looks like comparing signed 64-bit integers with values equivalent to max *sometimes* fails. Here is the following code:

```
void MyClass::testAndDo(int64_t x, int64_t y) {
  while (true) {
    int64_t point = this->height == 0 ? 0 : int64_t(1) << (this->height - 1);
    int64_t max = point - 1;
    int64_t min = -point;

    cout << "min: " << min << endl;
    cout << "max: " << max << endl;
    cout << "x: " << x << endl;
    cout << "y: " << y << endl;
    cout << "min <= x : " << (min <= x) << endl;
    cout << "x <= max: " << (x <= max) << endl;
    cout << "min <= y : " << (min <= y) << endl;
    cout << "y  <= max: " << (y <= max) << endl;
    cout << "INT64_MAX: " << INT64_MAX << endl;
    cout << "x <= INT64_MAX: " << (x <= INT64_MAX) << endl;
    cout << "max == INT64_MAX? " << (max == INT64_MAX) << endl;
    if (min <= x && x <= max && min <= y &&
      y <= max) {
      break;
    }

    this->height += 1;
  }
  doStuff();
}
```

For my given test case x is -9223372036854775806 (so INT64_MIN + 2), and y is -9223372036854775808 (INT64_MIN).

The output of the cout's in that function is as follows:

```
min: -9223372036854775808
max: 9223372036854775807
x: -9223372036854775806
y: -9223372036854775808
min <= x : 1
x <= max: 0
min <= y : 1
y  <= max: 0
INT64_MAX: 9223372036854775807
x <= INT64_MAX: 1
max == INT64_MAX? 1
```

So I am pretty perplexed - x is NOT less than max, but x IS less than INT64_MAX, and max equals INT64_MAX.

Can anyone explain what is going on, or what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: What compiler are you using? How is `maxPoint` defined? Can you make a small program that shows the issue? I tried this in VS2013 and didn't get the problem. (i.e. I got `x <= max : 1`). Example: http://ideone.com/u0UFKh

Comment: `int64_t max = maxPoint - 1;` but `max` is the same with `INT64_MAX`, if `maxPoint` is not a `std::uint64_t` then maybe some undefined behavior

Comment: Oops I'm sorry, I copy-pasted this and cleaned it up so only the relevant parts are there, and I should have replaced the occurrences of maxPoint with point. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TheDark I am using clang++ 8.0.0

Comment: I also tried g++ 4.2.1 and am getting the same error.

Comment: when `height` reach 64, we will have an undefined behavior. Can you change `point` to an `std::uint64_t` (add some check, of course) and try again?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly due to optimization, so having a small fragment of the code may not be enough to reproduce it.